# how to implement Loss function of paper ''Semantic Image Inpainting with Deep Generative Models' in keras

Tags: keras

I have trained GAN on celebA dataset. After that i separate G and D. Then i pick one image from celebA training dataset say yTrue and now i want to find the closest image to yTrue that G can generate say yPred. So the loss at output of G is ||yTrue - yPred||_2^{2} and i minimized it w.r.t generator input(latent variable from normal distribution). Below is code that is giving good results. Now the problem is i want to also add prior loss (log(1-D(G(z))) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pid58.png) in first line but i am not getting how to do it as D is not connected to G now and if i directly add k.mean(k.log(1-D.predict(G.output))) in first line it returns numpy array not tensor that is not allowed.

```
    `loss = K.mean(K.square(yTrue - gf.output))
     grad = K.gradients(loss,[gf.input])[0]
     fn = K.function([gf.input], [grad])
     generator_input = np.random.normal(0,1,[1,100])
     for i in range(5000):
         grad1 = fn([generator_input])
         generator_input -= grads[0]*.01
     recovered = gf.predict(generator_input)`
```

Answer (score 0):

In keras, you get the final output to create loss functions. Then, you will have to train the full network to achieve that loss. (Train G+D joined as a single model).

In the loss function, you will have `y_true` and `y_pred`, and you use them to compare:

PS: if MSE is not taking the output of the discriminator, please detail your questoin better.

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    mse = K.mean(K.square(yTrue-yPred)
    prior = K.mean(K.log(1-yPred))
    return mse + prior
```

Pass this function when compiling the model

```
discriminator.compile(loss=customLoss,optimizer=.....)
```

Comment: Sorry, gotta go, I can't update my question until monday now. But make a model with two outputs, one from G, the other from D ,keep them connected, though. Use one loss for each output.